# Replace interior of matrix with zeros

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, algorithm

I have f.e. the following square matrix:

```
x = {{2, 5, 5, 11, 11, 23, 37, 41, 43, 47},
    {2, 5, 11, 17, 19, 23, 41, 41, 43, 67},
    {2, 7, 11, 19, 19, 41, 41, 43, 47, 73},
    {3, 11, 17, 19, 23, 41, 43, 53, 67, 79},
    {3, 11, 19, 19, 31, 43, 47, 59, 67, 83},
    {3, 17, 19, 29, 37, 43, 53, 59, 73, 83},
    {5, 17, 29, 31, 37, 47, 53, 71, 73, 83},
    {7, 19, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 73, 73, 89},
    {11, 23, 31, 41, 43, 53, 61, 73, 79, 97},
    {29, 29, 37, 41, 53, 67, 71, 79, 79, 97}};
```

I want to keep the first and last row / column and replace all other numbers with `0`. I have written:

```
n = Length@First@x;

Table[x[[i, j]] = 0, {i, 2, n - 1}, {j, 2, n - 1}];

x // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Before that I tried to find a more functional solution (f.e. with replacement patterns) but gave up after some unsuccesful attempts. Thanks for showing me some alternatives.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just another alternative.

```
x - ArrayPad[ArrayPad[x, -1], 1] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Quite an unusual approach but I like it.

Comment: Could also be written: `x - Fold[ArrayPad, x, {-1, 1}]`

Comment: @Pickett Without doing any speed comparisons I would like to accept your answer because it is so clever and, like Mr. Wizard remarked, "unusual".

Comment: @eldo Thank you! :)

Answer (score 21):

You can do:

```
x[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] = 0;
x
```

or

```
ReplacePart[x, {i, j} -> 0 /; And @@ MapThread[Less, {{1, 1}, {i, j}, Dimensions@x}]]
```

Comment: Probably THE answer. Actually I tried `Part` but wasn't able to find your sequence.

Comment: This is what I thought to use as well, but please note that this does in-place modification.  That's often advantageous but if you don't want it you'll have to make a copy.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree, now there is something different too :)

Answer (score 10):

Although I believe that Kuba's first method is the best approach here is another:

```
zerofill[a_] := a (1 - BoxMatrix[#/2 - 2, #]) & @ Dimensions @ a
```

Now:

```
Array[Times, {5, 8}] // zerofill // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\
>  3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \\
>  4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32 \\
>  5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 & 40
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: An equivalent method: `zerofill[a_?MatrixQ] := (1 - BoxMatrix[Quotient[#, 2, 1] - 1, #]) &[Dimensions[a]] a`

Answer (score 10):

This performs quite well on large matrices, seems to outrun the others I've tested so far:

```
Module[{z = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@#]},
  z[[1, All]] = #[[1, All]];
  z[[All, 1]] = #[[All, 1]];
  z[[-1, All]] = #[[-1, All]];
  z[[All, -1]] = #[[All, -1]];
  z] &
```

For really large arrays, it would behoove one to work in the sparse domain, where the following is even faster and certainly more memory efficient:

```
With[{r = First@Dimensions@#, c = Last@Dimensions@#},
  SparseArray[
   Join[Tuples[{{1}, Range@c}], Tuples[{{r}, Range@c}], 
        Tuples[{Range@r, {1}}], Tuples[{Range@r, {c}}]] -> 
    Join[#[[1]], #[[r]], #[[All, 1]], #[[All, c]]], {r, c}]] &
```

Comment: I never expected this to be faster than `x[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]]` but it is! Big +1!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, I was surprised (a bit - I expected faster, just not the degree) - but makes sense - less copy (direct or pointer) involved. I kind of like the update sparse method - even faster than the order of magnitude faster than accepted of the first (would be nice if posters specified they want 'clever' vs efficient)... Thx for +!

Comment: @rasher I'm sorry, I tested your code (and upvoted it), but I don't have enough experience to make reliable speed comparisons.

Answer (score 8):

### [MorphologicalPerimeter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalPerimeter.html)

```
x MorphologicalPerimeter[$MaxMachineNumber + x] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  2 & 5 & 5 & 11 & 11 & 23 & 37 & 41 & 43 & 47 \\
>  2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 67 \\
>  2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 73 \\
>  3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 79 \\
>  3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 83 \\
>  3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 83 \\
>  5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 83 \\
>  7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 89 \\
>  11 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 97 \\
>  29 & 29 & 37 & 41 & 53 & 67 & 71 & 79 & 79 & 97 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

If there are no zeros on the perimeter of the input matrix, you can use
`MorphologicalPerimeter[x]` instead of `MorphologicalPerimeter[$MaxMachineNumber + x]`.

```
# MorphologicalPerimeter[$MaxMachineNumber + #] &@RandomInteger[5, {5, 15}] // 
  MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
>  4 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
>  3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
>  0 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 7):

```
n = Dimensions[x];
ReplacePart[x, {i_, j_} /;2 <= i <= n[[1]] - 1 && 2 <= j <= n[[2]] - 1 :> 0]
```

another way:

```
MapAt[0 &, x, {2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2}]
```

Comment: +1. Just `0 &` is enough.

Comment: @ Pickett, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @kuba, thanks,I have modified it for non square matrices.

Answer (score 3):

```
       # ArrayPad[ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@# - 2], 1, 1] &@ 
             Array[Times, {5, 8}]
```

or

```
       # SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@
           Flatten[{#, Reverse@# } &@ 
                  {_, #} & /@ {1, -1}, 1],
                    Dimensions@#] &@  Array[Times, {5, 8}]
```

Answer (score 3):

A variation on @rasher's post:

```
border = Module[{a = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@#], i = {1, -1}}, 
                {a[[i]], a[[All, i]]} = {#[[i]], #[[All, i]]}; a] &

border@x //MatrixForm
```

[image]

and another `SparseArray` variation

```
border2 = Module[{a = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@# - 2], d = Dimensions@#}, 
                  # SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}] -> a, d, 1]] &
```

Answer (score 3):

All the good answers are given. For fun, here is one using `SparseArray`

```
 {n, m} = Dimensions[x];
 x = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == 1||j == m||i == 1||i == n} :> {x[[i, j]]}, {n, m}];
 MatrixForm[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Kuba good point, easy to fix, will do in sec