# Replace elements in some region in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I want to replace some elements in list.

Assume that we have

```
A={{1,2,3,4},
   {5,6,7,8},
   {9,10,11,12},
   {13,14,15,16}}
```

and we want to replace elements `A[[i,j]]` to `30` such that `[i,j]` is in `{(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3)}`

Then, the result is following:

```
B={{1,2,3,4},
   {5,30,30,8},
   {9,30,30,12},
   {13,14,15,16}}
```

We can do it using `Replace` but, as you know, it is very cumbersome and it is not a good idea if the list has large dimension.

If you have fancy method for this, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: For large arrays you should have a look at [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html?q=SparseArray).

Comment: Related: [(52385)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52385/121)

Answer (score 10):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

[`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) can be used with explicit positions

```
b = ReplacePart[a, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} -> 30]
```

or with positions matching a pattern

```
b = ReplacePart[a, {(2 | 3), (2 | 3)} -> 30]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
>  {5, 30, 30, 8}, 
>  {9, 30, 30, 12}, 
>  {13, 14, 15, 16}}
> ```

or

```
b = ReplacePart[a, {i_, j_} /; 1 < i < 4 && 1 < j < 4 -> 30]
```

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way is usually an assignment on `Part`, and it generalizes well.
(See my comments in [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/3077#3077).)

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

B = A;
B[[2 ;; 3, 2 ;; 3]] = 30;
B // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 30 & 30 & 8 \\
 9 & 30 & 30 & 12 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Less efficiently but cleanly you can also use `MapAt` is a slightly nonstandard way:

```
MapAt[30 &, A, {2 ;; 3, 2 ;; 3}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 30 & 30 & 8 \\
 9 & 30 & 30 & 12 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$